# Issue with the interpretation of Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I’m having an issue with the terminology and perception authors use. Some authors perceive PL as a branch of logic “with subsets” with classical or truth-functional PL as these subsets. Other perceive PL as a logic which influences other logics like modal logic but it itself is independent. I’m unsure what to do with this.

Comment: There is nothing you can do about it, authors will use terms as they see fit. In a narrow sense, people use "propositional logic" just for the standard Boolean logic on propositions. In a broad sense,  it can be used for its extensions without quantifiers or their equivalents, including modal propositional logic, see e.g. [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/prop-log/#H8). Just note the ambiguity, with references, and state how *you* will use it.

Comment: What about the perception?

Comment: Perception of which label to use for which purpose? It is a matter of taste and practicality.

Comment: There are different "levels of abstraction" in the way logic models human language: with prop logic we have only connectives linking sentences. With predicate logic we have a finer analysis of the sentence in predicates (relations) and objects.

Comment: The "interesting" part is FOL, because only with it we can model mathematical theory. Thus, in principle, we can dispense with propositional logic... BUT prop logic is very useful from the pedagogical point of view. A typical ML textbook starts with prop logic because with its "toy language" it is easier to explain some basic concepts: truth-functional connectives, logical consequence, validity.

Comment: Propositional logic can be described as 'zero-order' logic, because it does not quantify over things. It contrasts with first-order logic, which permits quantification over things, and second-order logic, which permits quantification over properties of things. Also, it does not have to be classical. The propositional fragment of intuitionistic logic can correctly be called a propositional logic. It's just that classical logic is so ubiquitous that people often assume it without making it explicit.